# Is there a certain way you need to call targetObjectId?

Tags: trigger, singleemailmessage

So normally I would send an email by normal means and without code but I need to do a query on our Team__c object to find out who I would need to send it to. I am trying to send an email to any "squad" that has a marketing rep = to the opportunity owner. Now the error that I am receiving is:

> Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error:
>   CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, mdrEmailSend: execution of
>   BeforeInsert caused by: System.EmailException: SendEmail failed. First
>   exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_TYPE_FOR_OPERATION, Only
>   User, Contact, Lead, or Person objects are allowed for targetObjectId:
>   a6Y0m0000008SQz.: [targetObjectId, a6Y0m0000008SQzEAM]
>   Trigger.mdrEmailSend: line 21, column 1: [] Error is in expression
>   '{!submit}' in component  in page
>   handoffformarketing: Class.mdrHandOffOppInsert.submit: line 23, column
>   1

This email is supposed to be kicked off they they insert a record with a marketing opportunity = true. I guess my biggest confusion that I have is that the people it is sending this to are look ups to the user object and I am trying to pull them into my list and then send it the list. Is there something that someone sees that I might be doing incorrectly?

```
trigger mdrEmailSend on Opportunity (before insert) {

for(Opportunity opp :trigger.New){
    if(opp.Marketing_Opp__c = true) {

        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage(); 

        List <Team__c> Squad= [select id, Account_Director__r.email from Team__c where marketing_development_rep__c =:opp.ownerid]; 
        List <String> toEmail = new List <String>();
        for (Team__c s:Squad) {
            toEmail.add(s.Account_Director__r.email);
        }
        mail.setTargetObjectId(Squad[0].id); 
        mail.setSenderDisplayName('Salesforce Support'); 
        mail.setToAddresses(toEmail);
        mail.setUseSignature(false); 
        mail.setBccSender(false); 
        mail.setSaveAsActivity(false); 
        EmailTemplate et=[Select id from EmailTemplate where Name=:'MDR Sales Handoff Initial Alert' limit 1]; 
        mail.setTemplateId(et.id); 
        Messaging.SendEmailResult [] r = Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please note that your code may cause problems, as you have queries in a loop, and sendEmail in a loop. Your trigger should be bulkified before sending to production. Also, `if(opp.Marketing_Opp__c = true)` is always true, and will set the field to true as well, which is not what you're trying to do (presumably). Make sure you write a unit test that includes 51 opportunities. If it passes, then you're ready for production.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox. This wont always be the case as for Marketing_Opp__c to equal true it would need to be check from a button that kicks off the initial apex class (controller). So this will actually be a rare situation.

Comment: No, I'm trying to say that `=` is *assignment*, so you will be forcing the value to true. This is a logic bug. You need to use `==` to check for *equality*.

Comment: Ah I get that. I apologize for my confusion and thank you for catching that error I had.

Answer (score 1):

As the error suggests, this is your problem location:

```
mail.setTargetObjectId(Squad[0].id);
```

`Squad[0]` is a `Team__c` object, not a `Lead`, `Contact` (or Person Account), or `User`.

If `Team__c` contains a user lookup, you need to pass the contents of that lookup field to `setTargetObjectId()`. It looks like this may be `Team__c.Account_Director__c`.

Note that `setToAddresses()` is not required when you are specifying the recipient with `setTargetObjectId()`.